# Stop Mac OS from re-creating ~/Pictures, ~/Music, or ~/Public

Tags: macos, user-accounts

I've configured iTunes, iMovie, etc to never use my ~/Movies or ~/Pictures directories, and I personally never use ~/Public.  However, something keeps re-creating these directories (and putting just a single file, ".localized" in them).

How can I stop Mac OS from doing this without my consent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can hide them, though:

```
chflags hidden ~/Pictures
```

Comment: Yes, these folders are used by the system and can't be deleted without messing up your system.

Comment: "chflags" doesn't hide anything -- it just tells the Finder not to show the directory (still visible in Terminal, for example). @mark And "the system" is too vague to make any sense.