# rm'd dirs in Users/home/ reappear in OSX

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop Mac OS from re-creating ~/Pictures, ~/Music, or ~/Public](https://superuser.com/questions/139702/stop-mac-os-from-re-creating-pictures-music-or-public)

Hi, I su'd to root and deleted some stock directories in my home folder such as Documents, Music, Pictures via rm -Rf. They were indeed deleted, but the next time I went to my home folder in Finder, the folders were re-created. How do I stop this behavior? I am using Snow Leopard (OSX 10.6.6).

Answer (score 1):

You can't. They'll just keep being recreated. *Maybe* by taking away your own file system permissions, but you definitely don't want that.

Try setting the *hidden* flag to make them invisible, that's the best you can get.

```
chflags hidden ~/Movies
```

Comment: chflags hidden is what I am doing already. There has got to be a way to do this. What replaces the directories? Must be a daemon of some kind, and launchd must be launching it. I wonder if a change would affect the repopulation of dirs globally or by user.

Comment: @adamlogan You could try using `dtrace`, or `fs_usage` or something like that to determine which process is responsible, and try blocking that.

Comment: @adam I'm currently running `dtrace` to log file accesses, and a folder action for visible feedback once `~` is modified. No luck so far.

Comment: @adam `Music` was just created when QuickLooking an audio file, either by the process `quicklookd` or `Finder` itself. Do you see a way to prevent this? I don't.